# Select Stoppage time from PLC recored

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
_timestamp            throughput_net
2019-05-01 07:46:08.000    15.8
2019-05-01 07:46:38.000    15.8
2019-05-01 07:47:09.000    15.8
2019-05-01 07:47:39.000    15.8
2019-05-01 07:48:09.000    15.8
2019-05-01 07:48:39.000    15.8
2019-05-01 07:49:09.000    15.8
2019-05-01 12:46:52.000    0
2019-05-01 12:47:22.000    0
2019-05-01 12:47:53.000    0
2019-05-01 12:48:23.000    0
2019-05-01 12:48:53.000    0
2019-05-01 12:49:23.000    0
2019-05-01 12:49:53.000    0
2019-05-01 12:50:23.000    0
```

The above values I am getting from a machine PLC every minute 30 Sec, the throughput for the machine is 1500 KG/hr but during machine stoppage, the throughput will be like data above.

The question is I need the output to be like the table below

```
 ---------------------------------------
|    From    |     To    | Period in min|
 ---------------------------------------
| 07:46:08   | 07:49:09  |     3        |
| 12:46:52   | 12:50:23  |     4        |
 ---------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to group your log into periods of where the machine were running or stopped, you can use the following code:

```
SELECT  MIN(_timestamp) AS [From],
            MAX(_timestamp) AS [To],
            DATEDIFF(MINUTE, MIN(_timestamp), MAX(_timestamp)) AS [Period in min],
            (CASE WHEN AVG(throughput_net) > 0 THEN 'Running' ELSE 'Stopped' END) AS [Status]

    FROM (
            SELECT  yourtable.*,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER   (ORDER BY _timestamp) AS seqnum,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER   ( PARTITION BY (
                                            CASE WHEN throughput_net > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
                                          )
                                          ORDER BY _timestamp) AS seqnum_t
            FROM yourtable
    ) t

    GROUP BY (seqnum - seqnum_t);
```

Answer (score 0):

The naive method is aggregation.  This seems to do what you want:

```
select min(_timestamp), max(_timestamp), throughput,
       datediff(day, min(_timestamp), max(_timestamp)) as period_in_min
from t
group by througput;
```

However, you probably want this treated as a gaps-and-islands problem.  That is the `0` values could appear as "islands" and you want a separate row in the result set for each island.

If so, you can use the different of row numbers method:

```
select min(_timestamp), max(_timestamp), throughput,
       datediff(day, min(_timestamp), max(_timestamp)) as period_in_min
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by _timestamp) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by throughput order by _timestamp) as seqnum_t
      from t
     ) t
group by (seqnum - seqnum_t), througput;
```

It is a little tricky to explain how this works.  However, if you look at the results of the subquery, you will see why the difference in the two row number values identifies the adjacent constant values.